# Why are the buttons and text field not displaying in the same line?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm implementing a page in which I need three buttons and one textfield in same horizontal plane (same line). When  implementing it it comes out vertically.
How can I solve this issue?
Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/3LEdJ/).

I am using this:

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">

                            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"  >
                               <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" >Search</a>
                               <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false">Next</a>
                               <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" >Previous</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this

```
data-inline="true"
```

So the result will be this

```
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"  >
                          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" >Search</a>
                         <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true">Next</a>
                            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" >Previous</a>
                    </div> 
 <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">


            <div
```

This can be found in the jquery mobile docs here
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-inline.html

Comment: On click any button i need to show .On any click button i need to hide this

Comment: Not working Buttons are Horizontal plan But next field is on above the buttons..:(